# Figure out how it is compressed?

Tags: c#, compression

I have a archive (I know its a game compression) and I am trying to figure out how it is compressed so I can add files to it using C#. It opens/works in 7zip, and winrar. But when I use ZipForge/ComponentAce archive reference it says Invalid File.

Any help?

- Steve

Comment: More information is needed, specifically the extension and the first few bytes in text or hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you opened the file up in a binary editor to see if the first few bytes denote the format?

For example ZIP files have the header format given on here http://www.ta7.de/txt/computer/computer016.htm

What extension does the file have?

Comment: The first couple of bytes say PK (50 4B). The ending is .s2z (game file compression).

Comment: Also, if I rename the file to .zip I can do what ever I want with it. Maybe I could just rename it both ways, but I don't want to risk corrupting it.

Comment: Why do you need to modify the game data? Looks like it probably just standard PKZip so you're probably ok to rename it. Just create a backup and have a go.